# Is it possible to assign a 'Queue Build' permission to a service principal?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

...subj.

I mean 'Service Principal' = security identity used by user-created apps, services, and automation tools to access specific Azure resources. = 'User identity' (login and password or certificate) with a specific role, and tightly controlled permissions to access resources.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to assign a 'Queue Build' permission to a service principal?

Azure devops provided the most common built-in security groups—**Readers**, **Contributors**, and **Project Administrators**.

We could check and set the [Default permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/permissions-access?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fsecurity-access-billing%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fsecurity-access-billing%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops#azure-pipelines) for those groups:

[image]

If your service principal requires more granular permissions settings, we could go to the Permissions of the pipeline:

[image]

We could add the user to the one of default groups and set the permissions for that group. We could even custom the group for the service principal: Go to project settings-> Permissions-> Groups->New Group:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: But how do you add a service principal as a DevOps user?